# Call ExitWindowsEx in NASM

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

I have this NASM code

```
extern GetStdHandle 
extern WriteFile 
extern AllocConsole 
extern FreeConsole 
extern SetConsoleTitleA 
extern SetConsoleCursorPosition 
extern Sleep 
extern ExitProcess 
extern ExitWindowsEx


import GetStdHandle kernel32.dll 
import WriteFile kernel32.dll 
import AllocConsole kernel32.dll 
import FreeConsole kernel32.dll 
import SetConsoleTitleA kernel32.dll 
import SetConsoleCursorPosition kernel32.dll 
import Sleep kernel32.dll 
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll 
import ExitWindowsEx user32.dll

. 
section .text use32 

..start: 

call [ExitWindowsEx]
```

When I execute it, it doesn't perform the function which is turning off the computer. I read that it requires parameters but how exactly do we pass the parameters like this in C#

[image]

Comment: "To shut down or restart the system, the calling process must use the AdjustTokenPrivileges function to enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges." ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using 32-bit Intel architecture. In this case you have to pass the arguments in the stack.

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
push eax
push ebx
call [ExitWindowsEx]
```

Comment: how do we include user32 and extern and call exitwindowsex in tasm?

Comment: I don't know about TASM sorry.